# Creating a GUI using Tkinter to select CSV files in a pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to use Tkinter to create a GUI for the user to select the .CSV files that will be cleaned up in a Pandas DF. The user will also select the output path and filename. I've compiled the following code but have run to a standstill and have no idea how to actually run the selected files with tkinter.

```
window = Tk()
def browse_button():
    global folder_path
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=window,title='Select an Excel File',filetypes=[("Excel Files", ".xlsx; *.csv; *.xls")])
    window.tk.splitlist(filename)
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)
def file_save():
    global folder_path2
    savefilename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".csv",parent=window,title='Select the Save Location',filetypes=[("Excel Files", ".xlsx; *.csv; *.xls")])
    folder_path2.set(savefilename)
    print(savefilename)
def run_button():
    global folder_path3

window.title("Excel Program")

Label(window, text="Insert CSV").grid(row=0)
Label(window, text="Save").grid(row=1)
e1 = Entry(window)
e2 = Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

folder_path = StringVar()
e1 = Label(master=window,textvariable=folder_path)
button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)

folder_path2 = StringVar()
e2 = Label(master=window,textvariable=folder_path2)
button3 = Button(text="Save Location", command=file_save)
button3.grid(row=1, column=3)

folder_path3 = StringVar()
e3 = Label(master=window,textvariable=folder_path3)
button4 = Button(text="Run", command=run_button)
button4.grid(row=3, column=3)


path = ("Original pandas code path goes here")
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df) for df in files], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
pattern = r'Patterns go here'
match_idx = [i for i, e in enumerate(df.columns) if re.search(pattern, e)]
drop_cols = match_idx[3:]
usecols = [idx for idx, e in enumerate(df.columns) if idx not in drop_cols]
df1 = df.iloc[:, usecols]
df2 = df1.replace(['; ','_', regex=True)

df2.to_csv(r"save path goes here",header=False, index=False)

window.mainloop()
```

The goal here is for the selected .CSV files using the `browse_button()` to be the input for `files` and for the `file_save()` selected path to be the save location seen in `df2.to_csv`. I would like to use the `run_button()` to run the pandas script but my searching has not really helped me complete that (I am really new to pandas/tkinter and haven't touched python for years until recently, so sorry for the newbie questions). Any help is appreciated, as I said, I just don't know how to proceed or to even tie together both scripts and everything I've searched here is too advanced for my knowledge. Thanks!